# how to include pyttsx library in python

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I am learning python.Now i am trying to deploy an application where user will get output in the form of voice.I came with a library named pyttsx.
So i copied folder pyttsx in lib folder.But its giving me error as

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\bot.py", line 10, in <module>
  engine = pyttsx.init()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pyttsx\__init__.py", line 39, in init
  eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pyttsx\engine.py", line 45, in __init__
  self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pyttsx\driver.py", line 64, in __init__
  self._module = __import__(name, globals(), locals(), [driverName])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pyttsx\drivers\sapi5.py", line 19, in <module>
  import win32com.client
  ImportError: No module named win32com.client
```

the package had come with other folders and files too

here is the tree structure of same

├───docs

├───pyttsx

```
       └───drivers
```

└───pyttsx.egg-info

As i am new to python can anyone tell me how to include library
i am using windows 7 home premium.and installation directory exist in c.

Answer (score 0):

You want the "python for windows" extension, available from
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/.

Answer (score 0):

First install the [pywin32-extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/) package using its Windows installer.
Then use:

```
pip install pyttsx
```

to install `pyttsx`.